# Can't & can update string pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers

When I get string from keyboard, the program works as expected, I can update the content of the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *cards;
    cards = malloc(256);
    fgets(cards, 256, stdin);
    char a_card = cards[2];
    cards[2] = cards[1];
    cards[1] = cards[0];
    cards[0] = cards[2];
    cards[2] = cards[1];
    cards[1] = a_card;
    puts(cards);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I set a char pointer to a string literal, the program crashed. I deleted line x to line y then program worked. I know that a char pointer can't be updated. But why it can be updated when it was read from keyboard?

```
int main()
{

    char *cards;
    cards = malloc(256);
    cards = "JQK";
    char a_card = cards[2];
    cards[2] = cards[1]; // line x
    cards[1] = cards[0];
    cards[0] = cards[2];
    cards[2] = cards[1];
    cards[1] = a_card; // line y
    puts(cards);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `strcpy(cards,  "JQK");` instead of `cards = "JQK";`.

Comment: `cards = "JQK"; ... cards[2] = ...` is attempting to modified a _string literal_.  That is undefined behavior.  Why write code to attempt that?

Comment: "I know that" is always followed by a false statement... A char pointer can be updated. But a string literal cannot be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The line `cards = malloc(256) ;` assigns the variable `cards` equal to a memory location to newly allocated memory from the heap.  The next line `cards = "JQK";` updates the variable `cards` equal to a memory location that is most likely someward inside the program's string table, which (normally) cannot be modified.  Then the line `cards[2] = cards[1];` tries to update a location in the string table, two characters after the location that `cards` points to.  That is what causes the crash.

Comment: "The next line `cards = "JQK";`" assigns the address of the *string literal* `"JQK"` which is an address inside the `.rodata` section of the executable. On Nix's you can confirm by dumping to assembly (e.g. `gcc -S -masm=intel -o output.asm yourprogram.c` or by using `objdump`. For other OS's, you will have to lookup the equivalent options and tools.